# android admob banner doesn't show in special case

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I'm using admob banner in android, everything work correctly, but except in this case:

Firstly, I turn off the Wifi and then open my app.

Secondly, I turn on the Wifi >>> banner doesn't show in current activity (main activity).

Thirdly, I do some action to open new activity in my app >>> banner shows on that activity

Fourthly, I come back to main activity >>> banner doesn't show.

That's mean banner only shows when I refresh my activity except in my main activity?

Please suggest me how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Every activity loads banner during its "onCreate()", so thats why it is visible in your second activity.So logically this is working fine if you consider a real user using your app.

Even then if you want to, then you should finish your MainActivity using:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG%5FACTIVITY%5FNO%5FHISTORY

[Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY][1]and the override " onBackPressed()" of your second activity to reload first activity from the scratch

Answer (score 0):

This is not something to be concerned about.

The AdView is responsible for displaying ads. If you have configured it (in the Admob dashboard) to auto refresh every X seconds then I would expect it to notice that it has a net connection again at some point and start serving ads.

You are much better off concentrating on your app/game itself.